# Will hit-for-miss and hit-for-pass be removed from Varnish using BAN

Tags: caching, varnish, cache-control, varnish-vcl

Our cache-control headers only change during deploys of the application. Our current deployment pipeline triggers a *BAN* on the whole site to flush the cache after a successful deploy. Will this *BAN* also remove any hit-for-miss and hit-for-pass objects from Varnish? We’re currently using the default 120sec TTL for hit-for-miss, but considering cranking that up significantly if *BAN* (or *PURGE*) also removes those objects as things will never magically become cacheable without a deploy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Banning, won't *flush* the cache, it will prevent content from being served and as a matter of fact it will ban content which will stay in cache untile TTL expires or until it gets hit by a request: https://docs.varnish-software.com/tutorials/cache-invalidation/
2. Purging would be the best approach here
3. Yes, banning will have effect on every single object you have in cache if you ban i.e. on "ReqURL ~ /"

Comment: So if I get a hit-for-miss on /foo and sett a TTL of two hours, then after 1 hour deploy a new version that  adds cacheability to /foo then do a BAN on the same resource the hit-for-miss will be flushed and /foo will from there on be able to be served from the cache? e.g next request for /foo will not get the hit-for-miss? Also, would it be most appropriate with hit-for-miss or hit-for-pass in this context?